# phpunit tests returning no assertions and all errors

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I am new to unit testing (and would really like to learn). I tried pulling down this repository (https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) and have been trying to run their unit tests they already have set up. I have it to the point where phpunit is running but when I run

```
phpunit tests
```

from the root directory I get:

```
Tests: 1411, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1411
```

I have tried running

```
phpunit --configuration tests/phpunit.xml
```

but then I get the error:

```
 Class "JohnKary\PHPUnit\Listener\SpeedTrapListener" does not exist
```

They have something in their documentation about running:

```
php phpunit.phar -c tests/phpunit.xml
```

but I get the error

```
Could not open input file: phpunit.phar
```

which is because of the way I have phpunit set up I'm sure...

Any suggestions on how to further trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have configured https://github.com/johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap to be used as a test listener in your `phpunit.xml` but have not (properly) installed this extension.

And if your PHP cannot find `phpunit.phar` then you are either not pointing it to the correct path or you have not downloaded / installed the PHPUnit PHAR, maybe because you chose to install PHPUnit via Composer. In that case the correct path would be `vendor/bin/phpunit`, of course.